# Show last and early tweet with Twitter API android

Tags: android, json, twitter

hello i just learn API Twitter in android. At the start of my application, is shows 20 tweets with this URL

> https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=name&count=20

I want to display the last 20 before 20 tweets that have been shown (with load endless) and all new tweet after tweet earlier 20 (with pull to refresh). but i don't know how the URL or method to get 20 last or newest tweet . how it's work ? sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

You need this page: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline found on this well documented page (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1)

The URI you likely want though is:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=name&count=20&max_id=[lowest-id-from-last-batch]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Android I recommend using the [Twitter4J library](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) for easy Twitter API calls and response handling.

With use of [Paging](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html#pagination) you can get the next 20 tweets (using Paging.page) or new tweets (using id's or time/since).

Code example for getting a Users timeline using Twitter4J in Android:

```
// Use as field
Twitter twitter;

// Get timeline
try {
    if(twitter==null) {
        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(Constants.DEBUG)
                .setOAuthConsumerKey("YOUR CONSUMER KEY")
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret("YOUR CONSUMER SECRET")
                .setApplicationOnlyAuthEnabled(true)
                .setHttpConnectionTimeout(5000)
                .setHttpReadTimeout(5000)
                .setHttpStreamingReadTimeout(5000);
        twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
        twitter.getOAuth2Token();
    }
    return twitter.getUserTimeline("TwitterName", twitterPaging);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```